# Bootstrap typeAhead control customization

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I am working on Angular UI bootstrap typeahdead control, i am displaying the name information on typing. Now i want to show the additional information in case of duplicate names. is it possible to show the additional information in typeahead control, can we customize this control. I am using AngularJS as well.

Thanks

Comment: Of course it is possible, you can both customize a default template as described here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap#customize-templates or provide per-item template as shown on the demo page. It is kind of hard to say more without a minimal reproduce scenario.

Comment: Can i add the grid /table in custom template ?